# Question about when a script is executed after appending it

Tags: javascript

In my code, I have javascript that dynamically adds another script to the page:

```
created_script=document.createElement('script');
created_script.src='other_script';
created_script.type='text/javascript';
document.head.appendChild(created_script);
```

in this 'other script', I have a function called reloader().

The problem I'm having is that right after I dynamically add the script, I try to call the function reloader(), but I'm getting a reloader is not defined error.
Here's is like what I am doing:

```
created_script=document.createElement('script');
created_script.src='other_script';
created_script.type='text/javascript';
document.head.appendChild(created_script);
reloader();
```

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work and how should I fix this so that reloader() can be called after appending the script in a single dynamic call (if possible at all)?

Comment: Why not call `reloader()` in the same script that defines it?

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thanks! But I would still like to know why my original example didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Loading scripts like this happens asynchronously. This means that at the time you call `reloader()`, the external script may still be loading.

Your script shouldn't invoke `loader()` until it knows that the external script has completely loaded. See this related question: [How can I delay running some JS code until ALL of my asynchronous JS files downloaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800323/how-can-i-delay-running-some-js-code-until-all-of-my-asynchronous-js-files-downlo)

Comment: I'm curious, why is it that this happens asynchronously?

Comment: Presumably so your script doesn't hang while the resource is loaded. I guess it's the same as loading images.